# Xcode problem with resolving some spm package dependencies fetching stuck

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild, swift-package-manager

I have very strange problem with resolving packages in Xcode IDE. Some of the dependencies stuck at Resolve Packages phase when fetching.

What I've tried and what I've noticed:

```
force close xCode (normal close does not working because of Resolve Package stuck)
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/org.swift.swiftpm ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData ~/Library/org.swift.swiftpm ~/.swiftpm/xcode/
```

Then I tried in terminal:

```
xcodebuild -resolvePackageDependencies
```

And same problem. One package stuck when fetching.

But when I tried:

```
xcodebuild -resolvePackageDependencies -disablePackageRepositoryCache
```

Then it always works and all dependencies are resolving fine without any fetching issues. Now the question. Am I not cleaning project and repository cache using my `rm -rf` command? It is not enough or what?

Comment: `xcodebuild -resolvePackageDependencies -disablePackageRepositoryCache` worked for me